# Intercepting hydra with burp suite

Tags: brute-force, proxy, burp-suite, hydra

I'm using burp suite as a proxy and when I run hydra, burp suite should be able to catch that and log it in HTTP history, but instead of that I get the error

```
Can not connect [unreachable]
```

I tried `export HYDRA_PROXY_HTTP=http://127.0.0.1:8080` and `export HYDRA_PROXY=socks5:127.0.0.1:8118`, but none of that works.
Burp suite says, that proxy is running, it even intercepts firefox requests, but not hydra.

Command I use is this:

`hydra -l admin -p password -e ns -t 1 -F -u -w 10 -W 1 -v -V 127.0.0.1 http-post-form "/~bob/DVWA/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&user_token=${CSRF}&Login=Login:F=Location\: login.php:C=/404.php:H=Cookie: security=impossible; PHPSESSID=${SESSIONID}"`

and I get this

```
MacBook-Pro:Desktop bob$ hydra -1 admin -p password -e ns —t 1 —F —u —w 10 —W 1 —v —v 127.0.0.1 http-post-form "tybob/DVMA/login.php:username=ADSERa&password=APASS^&user token4(C) SRF}&Login=Login:F=Location\: login.php:C=/404.php:H=Cookie: security=impossible; PHPSESSID=WESSIONIDI"
Hydra v8.4 (c) 2017 by van Hauser/THC — Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes. 

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc—hydra) starting at 2017-03-18 14:43:40
[INFO] Using HTTP Proxy: http://127.0.0.1:8080 
[INFORMATION] escape sequence \: detected in module option, no parameter verification is performed. 
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 tasks, 3 login tries (1:1/p:3), —3 tries per task 
[DATA] attacking service http—post—form on port 80 
[DATA] with additional data /—bob/DVWA/login.php:username=nUSERA&password=^PASS^&user_token=39926bc7cff8584646ef71ab6f17cd88&Login=login:F=Location\: login.php:C=/404.php:H=Cookie : security=impossible; PHPSESSID=0018e65e3e7365e1f36a5dd5b375fac3 
[VERBOSE] Resolving addresses ... 
[VERBOSE] resolving done 
Process 2947: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[ATTEMPT] target 127.0.0.1 — login "admin" — pass "admin" — 1 of 3 (child 0] (0/0) 
Process 2947: Can not connect 
[unreachable] 
[ERROR] Child with pid 2947 terminating, cannot connect 
[VERBOSE] Retrying connection for child 0 
Process 2948: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[RE—ATTEMPT] target 127.0.0.1 — login "admin" — pass "" — 1 of 3 
[child 01 (0/0) 
Process 2948: Can not connect 
[unreachable] 
[ERROR] Child with pid 2948 terminating, cannot connect 
[VERBOSE] Retrying connection for child 0 
Process 2950: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[RE—ATTEMPT] target 127.0.0.1 — login "admin" — pass "password" — 1 of 3 
[child 0) (0/0) 
Process 2950: Can not connect 
[unreachable] 
[ERROR] Child with pid 2950 terminating, cannot connect 
Process 2951: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[REDO—ATTEMPT] target 127.0.0.1 — login "admin" — pass "password" — 2 of 4 
[child 0] (1/1) 
Process 2951: Can not connect 
[unreachable) 
[ERROR] Child with pid 2951 terminating, cannot connect 
Process 2953: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[REDO—ATTEMPT] target 127.0.0.1 — login "admin" — pass "password" — 3 of 5 (child 0] (2/2) 
Process 2953: Can not connect 
[unreachable] 
[ERROR] Child with pid 2953 terminating, cannot connect 
Process 2955: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[REDO—ATTEMPT] target 127.0.0.1 — login "admin" — pass "password" — 4 of 6 
[child 0] (3/3) 
Process 2955: Can not connect 
[unreachable] 
[ERROR] Child with pid 2955 terminating, cannot connect 
Process 2956: Can not connect 
[unreachable], retrying (1 of 1 retries) 
[STATUS] attack finished for 127.0.0.1 (waiting for children to complete tests) 1 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc—hydra) finished at 2017-03-18 14:44:00
MacBook—Pro:Desktop bob$
```

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzXbT.jpg)

I'm fairly new to this subject, so I don't exactly know what I'm always doing. I'm following a [tutorial](https://blog.g0tmi1k.com/dvwa/login/) I found. Can please someone explain what am I doing wrong? I understand that burp suite can't log hydra requests, because hydra doesn't connect via proxy, but why is that?

Comment: Can you show me where have you set the proxy ip to listen in Burp. I am guessing you have put it in mozilla. Share me the information, i think i can help.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bjsGl Here is screen shot of burp suite. I tried support invisible proxying, i tried socks5 proxy, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Yes that is place where burp is listening now where is the screenshot of traffic where you have forward the traffic to that IP and port.

Comment: I'm just guesing it's this. It's captured traffic, but that's all from firefox and not hydra http://imgur.com/a/ss3eD. If it's not it, please guide me trough where can i find it. In terminal i typed command export HYDRA_PROXY_HTTP=http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: I just figured something out. I can't use ip 127.0.0.1 in hydra command, instead type ifconfig and use your local ip, in my case 10.0.0.32, also update hosts file and add your ip address. Now i don't get that `Cannot connect [unreachable]` error, but burp suite still doesn't catch the traffic from hydra. Any help would be greatly appriciated.